# mysql query concatination error

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone tell me what is the wrong with the query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_monsoon_offer WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 4 DAY) = ' ".$date." ' AND user_monsoon_offer.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM transactions)";
```

Comment: What do you expect and what is your current result?

Comment: `echo $sql;` and paste that here

Answer (score 3):

I believe the extra whitespace you have in your concatenation is causing the problem.  Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_monsoon_offer 
        WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 4 DAY) = '$date' 
        AND user_monsoon_offer.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM transactions)";
```

Your original `WHERE` clause looked like the following:

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 4 DAY) = ' 2016-06-21 '
```

This won't work because of the extra spaces.

Comment: it is passing $date as string

Comment: What is the format of your date?  Paste it here as a comment or update your original question.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: No, show us the actual string which is being injected into the `WHERE` clause (and your query runs the risk of SQL injection, by the way).

Comment: i want to make the query like this   SELECT * FROM user_monsoon_offer 
        WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 4 DAY) = '2016-06-21' 
        AND user_monsoon_offer.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM transactions)

Comment: We're going in circles now, I already know what you want.  Can you show me the actual string query which your PHP code is generating?

Comment: do i show you the full code . i am not understanding what u r talking about

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for Dynamic data concatenation in filter condition.Use below condition.

```
SELECT * FROM user_monsoon_offer
WHERE SUBDATE(start_date,4) = ' ".$date." '
  AND user_monsoon_offer.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM transactions);
```